# How can I subscribe (or observe) the DOM window and callback upon any changes; not just for window resize events, scroll events, etc.?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to watch the window object for changes to any of it's properties and trigger an event whenever any properties change.

For example: `window.addEventListener('windowPropertiesChanged', () => {/* do something */})`

Can this be implemented with some kind of subscription or observer (mutation observer)? Is there a best practice for doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Mutation observer won't work because window isn't of type 'Node'. You could add it to the document, but it wouldn't see changes to the actual window object.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Any other ideas besides MutationObserver? In lieu of a setInterval(checkEntireWindow, tooOften) method is there any other option here? My understanding of window is limited and certainly could be overlooking some obvious reason why this isn't possible. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting.... how about shadowing the window object for your entire code and replacing it with a proxy?

```
let windowProxy = new Proxy (window, {
  get: function (target, prop) {
    console.log('Getting', target, prop);

    return target[prop];
  },

  set: function (target, prop, value) {
    console.log('Setting', target, prop);
    // Dispatch event here.

    target[prop] = value;

    return true;
  }
});

(() => {
    let window = windowProxy;

  // ALL YOUR CODE HERE

  window.scrollX = 5; // Setting Window ... scrollX
  console.log(window.scrollX); // Getting Window ... scrollX 5

})()
```

Or a bit hacky but I guess you could define getters and setters in the window object. It works somehow. This should catch all changes made from js (e.g. also from plugins etc)

```
let fakeWindow = {};

for (let key of Object.keys(window)) {
  let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, key);

  if (!descriptor.configurable) {
        continue;
  }

  fakeWindow[key] = window[key];

  Object.defineProperty(window, key, {  
    set: function (value) {
      console.log('Setting', key, value);
      fakeWindow[key] = value;

      return true;  
    },

    get: function () {
      return fakeWindow[key];
    }
  });
}

console.log(window.scrollX); // 0
window.scrollX = 5; // Setting scrollX 5
console.log(window.scrollX); // 5
```

EDIT: I just realized you probably want to track all internal changes made from the browser. I think your only option is manually looking for changes at a given interval.

```
let windowCopy = {};

for (let key of Object.keys(window)) {
    windowCopy[key] = window[key];
}

function check() {
  for (let key of Object.keys(window)) {
    if (window[key] != windowCopy[key]) {
      console.log('Changed', key, window[key]);
      windowCopy[key] = window[key];
    }
  }
}

setInterval(check, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I initially thought of this method, however, going this route, it seems that you'd either end up looping over the entire window object so frequently that it compromises UI events with check function frequently added to the call stack or try to fix this by throttling the function more and more until there is an undesirable lag between the window changing and check firing. I would rather have a function run as soon as the window changes and not block the call stack with heavy/frequent operations. I realize I may be overlooking a valid reason that this is not possible.

Comment: @mepley 
I do not believe it is possible to track changes made from native code in any other way, although it would be really cool. After all, they do not pass through javascript at all. Even the now deprecated Object.watch() and Object.observe() will not detect such changes. Technically, you only have to worry about properties native code changes. Out of the around 200 most are functions, which won't change - I doubt there are more then 20-30  which it changes, checking them even at every frame will be no performance problem. Every other change made from the code you can track with a Proxy.

Comment: Hmmm... okay. I will look into this method. Wasn't trying to shoot down your idea, was just a little concerned about blocking the call stack. Also, wanted to see if anyone else had any knowledge or ideas about this. I will try a few things here. Really appreciate your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Best of luck. If you actually find a way, I would really appreciate it if you shared.

Comment: Absolutely. Will post here. Thanks again